# Formatting Regex to use for a Java application

Tags: java, regex

I got a text document with a few pieces of information I want to suck out using the magic of regular expressions. I wrote a decent regex that catches the information I needed — you can look at it [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/uN3zX9/1).

The regex looks like this:

```
\w+(?!\>)(?=\-)\W+\w+|\w+\s+\w+(?!\>)(?=\s+\d+\s+)|\w+(?!\>)(?=\s+\d+\s+)
```

I rewrote it to use in Java — to my knowledge, you need to add an extra backslash, like so:

```
\\w+(?!\\>)(?=\\-)\\W+\\w+|\\w+\\s+\\w+(?!\\>)(?=\\s+\\d+\\s+)|\\w+(?!\\>)(?=\\s+\\d+\\s+)
```

The problem is that what it *should* catch (according to several regex sites) doesn't get catched when I use it in Java. Can anyone point out why this is?

EDIT: To clarify, my regex doesn't match *anything* in Java.

Comment: Be careful: the Java Regex engine is not the same as many other Regex engines. Could you please provide an example of what it is that you need to match, and what it is matching in Java?

Comment: There are several different flavors of regex. Have you tried it on a Java-specific website such as [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)?

Comment: @InsidiarumCrassescit – I see. If you follow my link in the description you can get a sense of what I wish to catch.

Comment: @RealSkeptic – I understand. No, I did not know of that site. Will take a look at it now.

Comment: What method are you using to evaluate the regex in Java? There are some methods that match an entire string and some that do partial matching. That may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't rely on all the lookaheads try using the following simplified pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\>([^\\d]+) ");
Matcher m = p.matcher(">Sea-Cucumber 576151 1HLB");
if (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));

// prints "Sea-Cucumber"
```